# facebook login api and unique userId

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

i am using facebook login in ios app, i have noticed that sometimes fb returns me different userId for the same user.

Is there any way to have a unique userid when i login the same user for different devices?

Thanks

Comment: User-ids are app-scoped since API v2.0 - meaning, you get to see a different user id, if you use a different app id. As long as the same app id is used, you should get the same app-scoped id every time.

Comment: thank you for your reply, its strange because i use the same app id,  i just login from different devices (iphones) and until now i have 2 different usersid for same email.

Comment: With the same app id, this should definitively not happen. If you can reproduce this at all, you should probably file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/